# When entering an ASCA agility trial how do I know if I should enter Novice A or B?

Tags: dogs, agility

I'm entering an ASCA agility trial for the first time, how do I know if I should enter Novice A or B? I am assuming that it is like AKC Novice A vs. Novice B, in that if the handler has ever titled a dog that they should enter Novice B. The dog I am entering has never trialed in ASCA before and I have never trialed in ASCA before. I do have several titles with this dog and others in other venues (USDAA and AKC) though so not sure which to enter.

Answer (score 2):

According to page 25 of http://www.asca.org/Portals/0/AgilityRules.pdf

> If the dog or handler has previously earned a Regular Agility Standard – Novice (RS-N) title, a Gamblers 
>   Agility Standard – Novice (GS-N) title, or a Jumpers Agility Standard – Novice (JS-N) title or any of the 
>   equivalents from any international style agility association, then they must enter in the Novice B category for that 
>   particular class.

So, because I have titles in USDAA and AKC then I enter him in Novice B.